# Google Drive API - Error creating a permission to try to make a created folder public on shared drive

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

**Ultimate Goal:**

Allow all files in a folder on a shared drive be publicly readable NOT editable.

**Issue:**

I have another simple problem that I'm sure is something silly I'm overlooking. I am simply trying to create a permission for a created drive folder on a shared drive to be publicly available via the link, as follows:

```
 const getFolderPerms = await drive.permissions.create({
        "fileId": `${createFolder.data.id}`,
        "requestBody": [
            {
                "role": "reader",
                "type": "anyone"
            }
        ],
        "supportsAllDrives": true,
        "supportsTeamDrives": true
    })
```

but when I attempt this I get the following error:

```
 message: 'Required parameter: fileId',
```

I know its actually sending a id over, because if I console log it before:

```
console.log('id ? ' + createFolder.data.id)
```

it prints out:

```
id ? 1fXLmWLLT5pi5WnztO6sYTzRqerowVucF
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried moving the requestBody to various functions but have still not been successful.

Comment: Instead of using a template string (\`${createFolder.data.id}\`) for the **`fileId`**, how about purely using createFolder.data.id without using template string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason for your current issue of `message: 'Required parameter: fileId',` is due to the value of `requestBody`.

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const getFolderPerms = await drive.permissions.create({
  fileId: `${createFolder.data.id}`,
  requestBody: {
    role: "reader",
    type: "anyone",
  },
  supportsAllDrives: true,
  supportsTeamDrives: true,
});
```

- In this modification, the value of `requestBody` is changed from an array to an object of the 1st element of your array.
- When this script is run with a valid file ID, I confirmed that the permission of the file could be changed.
- By the way, I think that when your file ID is a valid value, both `` fileId: `${createFolder.data.id}`, `` and `fileId: createFolder.data.id,` can be used.

#### Reference:

- [Method: permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/create)

Comment: Excellent, thank you soo much. Figured it was something simple!

Comment: @sylargaf Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.